# Golang MVC structure

Tags: function, design-patterns, model-view-controller, go

I searched many sites and I saw a lot of sources in GitHub and I haven't found a solution.

I created an MVC website pattern in Golang:

- app

  - controllers
  - models
  - lib (All the features class/functions)
  - middleware
  - router.go
- resources

  - views
- main.go

**My question is:** How to inject config to have everywhere settings and other implemented class that will always be needed (like load speed single page).

One more thing(additionally): Can anyone recommend me a good material or transcribe MVC tricks idea works MVC with Golang (General useful information).

Comment: No. You did not create MVC structure, You created a directory structure. Also, please not that "Model" should be singular, because it is the layer that contains the domain business logic.

Comment: Please take a look at some exists ones! like Spring in JAVA, Laravel in PHP, Rails is Ruby, etc.

Comment: @tereško yes, maybe one file model would be fine, but when i have a lot of code on model ? each model have "package models" so it won't be right ?

Comment: @PatrykGtfo I did not say that a model is a single file. **I said it is a single layer.** Do you know what application layers are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have one file called for example MainController where you can make functions for accessing database, sessions, config files and so on. All  you have to do really from there is to say something like this for example (inherit stuff from some other controller):

```
//MyController.go
type App struct {
    MainController
}

func (c Application) MyControllerFunc() returnTypeHere(http.Response for example) {

    //c.getDatabaseName is function from MainController that reads information from some plain text file or json file or similar
    someInfoFromConfigFile = c.getDatabaseName()
    var str []string
    str = append(str,  someInfoFromConfigFile)

    //RenderJson is function that render http response as json (Content type plain/json)
    return c.RenderJson(str)
}
```

But if you need mvc I suggest that you use some framework (Revel for example). I am using it all the time. It gives you that basic mvc functionality if you like and all other stuff is really up to you.
You keep you business logic in some helpers, models in models file etc.

You can check Revel main controller structure here:
https://github.com/revel/revel/blob/master/controller.go

Comment: Thanks for advice. I believe that the framework shortens job. Personally i want learn something because I will never learn using predefined rules... so at least I know how it works.

Comment: hey @pregmatch what is this function called the function that doesn't have a name  what this doing ```func (c Application) MyControllerFunc() returnTypeHere(http.Response for example)```